# MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv are still blocking when used in a for loop

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, matrix-multiplication

I have been trying to write a cannon's implementation of the Matrix Multiplication. Using MPI CVT, I am sending a few buffers using MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv. The program does not proceed during this send recv. I have tried using MPI_Waitall at different places but still, some of the processes stop responding. How do I fix this? Using MPI_Send and MPI_Recv gives the same error. However, without the initial shift, the cannon's algorithm loop works fine. It's just the initial shift that is having issues.

'''

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "mpi.h"
#include "math.h"

#define sz 9
#define UP 0
#define DOWN 1
#define LEFT 2
#define RIGHT 3
void mat_init(int a[sz][sz],int b[sz][sz]){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<sz;i++){
        for(j=0;j<sz;j++){
            a[i][j]=i+j;
            b[i][j]=i*j;}}
}

void mat_mult(int n, int a[n][n],int b[n][n], int c[n][n]){
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            for(k=0;k<n;k++){
                c[i][j] +=a[i][k]*b[k][j];}}}
}

void print_mat(int n, int a[n][n]){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);}printf("\n");}

}

int main(char *argv[],int argc)
{
    int comm_sz,rank;
    int i,j,k,n=3;
    int a[sz][sz],b[sz][sz],c[sz][sz];
    int a1[n][n],b1[n][n],c1[n][n];
    int nbrs[4];
    int dim[2];
    int n_dims=2;
    int periods[2]={1,1};
    int reorder = 0;
    int coords[2];
    int dir;
    int dis;

    mat_init(a,b);
    MPI_Status stats[9];
    MPI_Comm cartcomm;              // Cartesian Communicator

    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);            // Initialize MPI
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);    // Initialize Processors
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);       // Processors Rank

    if(rank==0){
        printf("A=\n");
        print_mat(sz,a);
        printf("B=\n");
        print_mat(sz,b);
    }

    dim[0] = sqrt(comm_sz);
    dim[1] = sqrt(comm_sz);

    dir = 0;
    dis = 1;
    MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, n_dims,dim,periods,reorder,&cartcomm);
    MPI_Cart_coords(cartcomm,rank,2,coords);

    MPI_Cart_shift(cartcomm, 0, dis, &nbrs[UP], &nbrs[DOWN]);
    MPI_Cart_shift(cartcomm, 1, dis, &nbrs[LEFT], &nbrs[RIGHT]);


    //Discretization
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            a1[i][j] = a[coords[0]*n+i][coords[1]*n+j];
            b1[i][j] = b[coords[0]*n+i][coords[1]*n+j];
            c1[i][j] = 0;
        }
    MPI_Request reqs[4];
    MPI_Request shiftreq[10];
    // Accounting initial shift
    for(int t=0;t<coords[1];t++){
        MPI_Isend(&a1, n*n, MPI_INT, nbrs[RIGHT], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[0]);
        MPI_Irecv(&a1, n*n, MPI_INT, nbrs[LEFT], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[1]);
        MPI_Waitall(2, reqs, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
    }

    for(int t=0;t<coords[0];t++){
        MPI_Isend(&b1, n*n, MPI_INT, nbrs[DOWN], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[0]);
        MPI_Irecv(&b1, n*n, MPI_INT, nbrs[UP], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[1]);
        MPI_Waitall(2, reqs, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){       // Cannon's Algorithm
         mat_mult(n,a1,b1,c1);
        //Shiftup
        MPI_Isend(&b1, n*n, MPI_INT, nbrs[UP], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[0]);
        MPI_Irecv(&b1, n*n, MPI_INT, nbrs[DOWN], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[1]);
        //Shiftleft
        MPI_Isend(&a1, n*n, MPI_INT, nbrs[LEFT], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[2]);
        MPI_Irecv(&a1, n*n, MPI_INT, nbrs[RIGHT], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[3]);
        MPI_Waitall(4, reqs, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);

    }
  
    MPI_Send(&c1,n*n,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&coords[0],1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&coords[1],1,MPI_INT,0,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rank==0){
        int drds[2];
       for(int t=0;t<comm_sz;t++){
            MPI_Recv(&c1,n*n,MPI_INT,t,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            MPI_Recv(&drds[0],1,MPI_INT,t,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            MPI_Recv(&drds[1],1,MPI_INT,t,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                    c[n*drds[0]+i][n*drds[1]+j] = c1[i][j];}}}
            printf("\nMatrix C:\n");
            for(i=0;i<sz;i++){
                for(j=0;j<sz;j++){
                    printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);}printf("\n");}}

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

'''

I have tried out many things and have found out that this is mostly an issue with sending and receiving to the neighbours. The algorithm takes care that for every send there exists a recv.

Comment: please include a [mcve] correctly formatted.

Comment: `for(int t=0;t<coords[?];t++)` is suspicious.

Comment: Note you cannot the same buffer for simultaneous non blocking send and receive. Instead, use `MPI_sendrecv_inplace(...)`

Comment: Yeah, the for(t=0:coords[?]) is a logic I came up with myself. I don't suppose this is how Cannon's Algorithm is often implemented. MPI_Sendrecv_replace() still faces the same issue. I did replace the Isend and Irecv with Sendrecv_replace, but it still becomes unresponsive.

Comment: So ask yourself what should be the number of iterations (in plain English), and if you are still stuck, I might be able to point you to how to get this value.

Comment: You were right, I do not need to send multiple shifting requests from each process. One shift should do the trick. I used a slightly different logic to find the shifting partners.

Comment: MPI_Cart_shift(cartcomm, 0, coords[1], &nbrs[UP], &nbrs[DOWN]);
MPI_Cart_shift(cartcomm, 1, coords[0], &nbrs[LEFT], &nbrs[RIGHT]);    MPI_Sendrecv_replace(&a1,n*n,MPI_INT,nbrs[LEFT],11,nbrs[RIGHT],11,cartcomm,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    MPI_Sendrecv_replace(&b1,n*n,MPI_INT,nbrs[UP],11,nbrs[DOWN],11,cartcomm,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    mat_mult(n,a1,b1,c1);

Comment: This finds the partners for each process to shift the A and B matrix. Thank you for the help.